# How to activate a Conda enviroment from inside JupyterHub?

Tags: conda, jupyterhub

I don't know if it is architecturally possible, but here is my problem.

I'm accessing a shared JupyterHub. I'd like to isolate some of my notebooks using different conda environment for each of them.

The main question is:

Can I activate a conda environment from a Jupyter Notebook that is already running in a JupyterHub?

Extra points if the answer also explains how would I create and initialize a conda environment from inside my already running Python kernel.

Comment: What you're probably looking for is the concept of [kernels](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html), where you can install a kernel for each environment you want to use. However, you wouldn't make that from inside the Notebook, it would be external and then select that kernel from the Notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using nb_conda - https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda , and ensuring that you are running JupyterHub from the base (*not an environment!*) should expose the kernel to your users.

Any environments that you have created/installed will then be available to run notebooks against.

in your base install

```
# Install nb_conda to allow environments be used as kernels
conda install nb_conda

# Launch your jupyterhub service
jupterhub
```

From within your Jupyter Notebook, you should now have the ability to change to the environment you wish by using Kernel -> Change Kernel. Your environments should be all available.

Simply restarting the kernel is akin to activating that environment.

Usefully, once you start doing this, your Jupyter Notebooks will start to save the kernel that the notebook is associated with, meaning that other users of your notebooks (*perhaps less well informed users shall we say*) don't need to know the ins and outs of your different environments.

With nb_conda, you will also get a conda 'tab' in JupyterHub home (*through browser*) which you can use to update / create environments too.

Comment: In my case, the nb_conda tab in Jupyter shows all environments, but the respective kernals didn't appear in the notebook drop-down menu. I had to install jupyter for the in each environment I wanted access to.